# Definition of $\mathbb{A}^n_S$ by glueing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Eisenbud and Haris (Geometry of schemes I.2.4), if $S=\cup_\alpha U_\alpha$ with the $U_\alpha$ affines, to define $\mathbb{A}^n_S$ one take $X=\cup_\alpha \mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha}$ with $\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha}=\operatorname{Spec} R_\alpha[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

Then the idea is to glue along the $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ but $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ is not affine so $\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha\cap U_\beta}$ has no meaning and even if $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ is affine, the induced morphism $\varphi_{\alpha,\beta}:\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}\to\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha}$ is not an open immersion so $X_{\alpha,\beta}:=\varphi_{\alpha,\beta}(\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta})\not\simeq\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}$ so $X_{\alpha,\beta}\not\simeq X_{\beta,\alpha}$.

So the question is: how to glue the $\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta}$ to build $\mathbb{A}^n_S$?

Edit: for $U_\gamma\subseteq U_\alpha$ affine one take the notation $\psi_{\alpha,\gamma}$ the induced morphism $\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\gamma}\to\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha}$.
I have the idea to take $X_{\alpha,\beta}=\cup_\gamma X_{\alpha,\gamma}$ where $X_{\alpha,\gamma}=\psi_{\alpha,\gamma}(\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\gamma})$ and the $\gamma$ so that $U_\gamma\subseteq U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ affines. Then if (1) the $\psi_{\alpha,\gamma}$ are open immersion then for all $\gamma$ one has $X_{\alpha,\gamma}\simeq X_{\beta,\gamma}$. But I don't see (2) how to conclude that $X_{\alpha,\beta}\simeq X_{\beta,\alpha}$ because the $X_{\alpha,\gamma}$ are only a covering of $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ and not a topology basis and so it is not enough (isn't?).

For the point (1) I see that if $(U_\alpha)_f\subseteq U_\alpha$ the $\mathbb{A}^n_{(U_\alpha)_f}\to \mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha}$ is an open immersion. But it is not enough because $(U_\alpha)_f$ has no reason to be a $(U_\beta)_g$.

So questions are

1) why the $\psi_{\alpha,\gamma}$ are open immersion?

2) how to conclude that $X_{\alpha,\beta}\simeq X_{\beta,\alpha}$?

Comment: Who says $\mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha \cap U_\beta} \to \mathbb{A}^n_{U_\alpha}$ isn't an open immersion? It is. Anyway, just take an open affine cover of $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... and 3): How to verify the cocycle condition?

Here is how to do all this without pain: Use the functorial point of view on schemes.

Consider the functor $(\mathrm{Sch}/S)^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$ defined by $T \mapsto \Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)^n$ (forgetting the ring structure on global sections). We claim that it is representable and the representing object will be our $S$-scheme $\mathbb{A}^n_S$; this is the conceptual definition/characterization of $\mathbb{A}^n_S$. There is a general criterion when such a functor is representable, see EGA I (1971), Chap. 0, Corollaire 4.5.5:

The functor has to be a sheaf when restricted to the open subsets of any fixed $S$-scheme and the functor has to be locally representable in the sense that there is an open covering $S = \bigcup_i S_i$ such that each restricted functor on $(\mathrm{Sch}/S_i)^{\mathrm{op}}$ is representable. The sheaf condition is trivial. For the local representability, take any open affine covering $S = \bigcup_i S_i$ and observe that each restricted functor is represented by the already known affine space $\mathbb{A}^n_{S_i}$ over the affine base $S_i$.

The mentioned criterion is very useful also for other constructions, e.g. fiber products, Spec for quasi-coherent algebras, Proj for graded quasi-coherent algebras. For more on this, you might read Brian Osserman's "Fiber products and Zariski sheaves", [pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/256A/notes/fiber-prods.pdf). By the way, if you already know fiber products, you might as well construct $\mathbb{A}^n_S$ as $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{Z}} \times_{\mathbb{Z}} S$.

Alternatively, for every locally ringed space $S$, we can construct a locally ringed space $\mathbb{A}^n_S$ over $S$ explicitly, which represents the functor $\mathsf{LRS}/S \to \mathsf{Set}$, $T \mapsto \Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)^n$. The underlying set is the set of pairs $(s,\mathfrak{p})$, where $s$ is a point in $S$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$. If $U \subseteq S$ is open and $f \in \mathcal{O}_S(U)[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$, then we consider the subset of those $(s,\mathfrak{p})$ for which $s \in U$ and $f_{s} \in \mathcal{O}_{S,s}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$ (we take stalks for each coefficient) is not contained in $\mathfrak{p}$. These sets constitute the basis for a topology. The structure sheaf is defined in such a way that the stalk at $(s,\mathfrak{p})$ is $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]_\mathfrak{p}$. The complete definition is a bit complicated, but sections consist of families of stalks which locally come from a fraction in $\mathcal{O}_S(U)[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]_f$. More generally, for every $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra $A$ we may explicitly construct the (relative) spectrum $\mathrm{Spec}_S(A)$; the above being the special case $A=\mathcal{O}_S[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$.